# How to open custom related record from page block table

Tags: apex, visualforce

"candidate" and "Task details" are two custom objects and have lookup relationship. I used page block Table to show task details filed values in which candidate_id is one field. I want to open candidate record after clicking candidate id from page block table. I am struggling to access it.

VF code :

```
<apex:page controller="displayCandidate">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageblock>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!candi}" var="item">
                <apex:column value="{!item.Name}"/>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Candidate__c.view,item.get(Candidate_Id__c).id)}" target="_blank">
                        {!item.Candidate_Name__r}
                    </apex:outputLink>
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public class displayCandidate {

    public List<Task_Details__c> candi { get; set; }

    public displayCandidate() {
        candi = [SELECT Id, Name, Candidate_Id__r.Id, Candidate_Name__c, Task__c, DSP_ID__c FROM Task_Details__c];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `URLFOR` syntax is incorrect.

var `item` represent each record from the `candi` list, so you can access the record id directly as follows:

```
<apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Candidate__c.view,item.Candidate_Id__c)}" target="_blank">
 {!item.Candidate_Id__r.Name}
</apex:outputLink>
```

You will need to add field `Candidate_Id__c` in the apex class SOQL and assumming you wanted to display the `Name` field of Candidate_Id__c, also add `Candidate_Id__r.Name` in the SOQL

Refer to this [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custom_links_constructing.htm&type=5) for more details

Comment: @mayur does this answer your question?